# Как включить перенос слов в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Есть у меня текст, что в одну строку не влезает и хотелось бы перенести его на следующие строки

Текст:

```
This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum. This is my test lorem ipsum.
A linebreak before this.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как включить перенос слов (word wrap)?

Comment: это наверное перенос строк, а не слов (в русской терминологии)

Comment: @Эникейщик, думаю, тут не перенос строк, т.к. нет разделителя строк. Поэтому перенос слов является корректнее :) `Перевод строки, или разрыв строки, — продолжение печати текста с новой строки, то есть с левого края на строку ниже, или уже на следующей странице. На компьютерах это осуществляется клавишей ввода Enter.` и `Включатель такого режима назвали переносом по словам (англ. word wrap)` из https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: так это "перевод", т. е. новая строка. Я же говорю про перенос - там же самая строка переносится (визуально) на другую линию. Перенос слов это когда одно слово печатается на двух строках (типографических).

Answer (score 5):

Перенос слов есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть несколько вариантов включить его:

1. Через команду меню `View/Word Wrap`:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Через комбинацию <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (для Mac: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>)
3. Через команду `editor.action.toggleWordWrap` в `Command Palette` (`View/Show Command Palette...`)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Глобально можно задать в настройках `settings.json`, в редакторе это `File/Preferences/Settings`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028495/5909792)